# How to distinguish whether $\lim {a_n\cdot b_n}$ exists or not, $\lim a_n=0$ and $\lim b_n$ doesn't exists

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

How to distinguish whether $\lim {a_n\cdot b_n}$ exists or not, $\lim a_n=0$ and $\lim b_n$ doesn't exists.

Comment: This isn't enough information to determine whether the limit of $a_nb_n$ exists.  Could you tell us why you're trying to figure this out?  Perhaps there is a bigger problem we can help with directly.

Comment: I've tried to divide it generally to two groups(those that have limit and those that don't) according to the $a_n$ and $b_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are following cases:

1, $\lim {a_n\cdot b_n}$ exists, however, $\lim {a_n}=0$ and $\lim {b_n}$ doesnot exist.

For example $a_n=\frac1n$ and $b_n=(-1)^n$;

2,  $\lim {a_n\cdot b_n}$ does not exist, however, $\lim {a_n}=0$ and $\lim {b_n}$ doesnot exist also .

For example $a_n=\frac1n$ and $b_n=n^2$;